# Haml Rails partial and locals issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, partial-views, local-variables, renderpartial

I just started playing around with haml and I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong.

**articles/edit.html.haml**

```
=render partial: 'form', f: f
  .submit_field
    =f.submit "Update Article"
```

**articles/_form.html.haml**

```
=form_for @article do |f|
  -if @article.errors.any?
  #error_explanation
    %h2
      =pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error")
      prohibited this task from being saved:
      %ul
        -@article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li=msg

  .text_field
    =f.label :title 
    %br
    =f.text_field :title

  .text_field
    =f.label :body
    %br
    =f.text_area :body, {rows: 10, cols: 40}
```

I get this error: **syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end** at .submit_field . Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the submit button in to your form partial:

**articles/edit.html.haml**

```
=form_for @article do |f|
  =render partial: 'form', f: f
```

**articles/_form.html.haml**

```
-if @article.errors.any?
#error_explanation
  %h2
    =pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error")
    prohibited this task from being saved:
    %ul
      -@article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li=msg

.text_field
  =f.label :title 
  %br
  =f.text_field :title

.text_field
  =f.label :body
  %br
  =f.text_area :body, {rows: 10, cols: 40}

.submit_field
  =f.submit "Update Article"
```

Comment: it works fine when I have it in my form function but I wanted to have "Update Article" for updating it and "Create New Article"  rather then "Create Article" for creating the new article so I needed the submit button outside. I was curious if I can do this because with erb tags it works fine. It was just something I was trying to figure out. This is what I will end up using though so thanks.

Comment: You could do this by reusing your form fields, but just pass in an extra parameter to your partial call.  Something like `=render partial: 'form', f: f, button_label: "Update Article"` for when you call the form from edit actions and `=render partial: 'form', f: f, button_label: "Create New Article"` for new actions.  Then, you'd just replace `=f.submit "Update Article"` with `=f.submit button_label`.  Hope that helps!